# pymongo 64bit unsigned integer

Tags: python, mongodb, unsigned, pymongo

I'm trying to insert a 64bit unsigned integer in mongodb using pymongo. The integer is the output of a CRC64 algorithm. I tried to following:

```
long(crc64(unicode(kw).encode('unicode-escape'))))
```

If I insert this into mongodb it starts to complain that only 64bit integers are supported by mongodb. Next I tried to convert it to a signed 64bit int like so:

```
ctypes.c_int64(crc64(unicode(kw).encode('unicode-escape')))).value
```

Which kind of works, mongodb stops complaining about the size of my int, but when I look at the data in mongodb I get this:

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "floatApprox" : -5307924876159732000,
        "top" : 3059119730,
        "bottom" : 2651469802 },
    "keyword" : "redacted",
    "normal_hash" : { 
        "floatApprox" : -671156942315906300,
        "top" : 4138701393,
        "bottom" : 549001936
    } 
}
```

What's going on here? Is there any way to put the 64bit int into the db as just an int (don't really care whether it's signed or unsigned.)

Comment: are you running mongo on a 32bit or 64bit machine?

Comment: Have you tried encoding it as binary?

Answer (score 5):

MongoDB uses BSON to store data, and the BSON spec says 64bit integer numbers are signed.

A sample session on a 64bit machine, 64bit mongo v2.0.1, python 2.6.5:

```
>>> num = long(9007199254740992)
>>> num
9007199254740992L
>>> bson = BSON.encode({"crc64":num})
>>> bson
'\x14\x00\x00\x00\x12crc64\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00'
>>> bson_str = bson.decode()
>>> bson_str
{u'crc64': 9007199254740992}
>>>
```

and running this script:

```
db.foo.save({"_id" : 1, "crc64" : long(9007199254740992)});

for doc in db.foo.find({"_id" : 1 }):
    crc = doc["crc64"]
    print("crc type: " + str(type(crc)))
```

prints:

```
crc type: <type 'int'>
```

and from the mongo shell:

```
> db.foo.findOne()
{ "_id" : 1, "crc64" : NumberLong("9007199254740992") }
>
```

Comment: Your long is not nearly long enough. Try doing the above with 2**64 instead of 9007199254740992. It will raise an OverflowError because as far as mongo is concerned, that number is too big. Unless you convert it to a int64 (that's signed.)

Comment: as i said, 64bit numbers are signed, which means [-2^63, 2^63-1] range, so you can't have 2^64. 9007199254740992 is certainly not a 32bit int.